# C# recursive delegate declaration problem

Tags: c#, delegates, declaration, forward

*** PLEASE SEE END FOR IMPORTANT EDIT ***

For various reasons I have something like:

`delegate void Task(QueueTask queueTask);
delegate void QueueTask(Task task);`

Using Visual Studio Express 2008 this works more or less fine apart from in lambda expressions where it can't deduce if I try call and call queueTask() in the function without explicit help:

```
void MyTask(QueueTask queueTask)
{
   queueTask(qt => {}); // fails with queueTask doesn't take 1 parameter?
}
```

This works though:

```
void MyTask(QueueTask queueTask)
{
   queueTask((QueueTask qt) => {});
}
```

Its not a huge problem and I know I could also probably get away by passing in another object that contained the delegate instead but I was curious if there was a way to make it work as its stands?

Thanks.

*** IMPORTANT EDIT BELOW ***

It seems only if I put the class 'TaskPool2' in a separate assembly I get the compile error!?

```
namespace Test
{
    public class TaskPool2
    {
        public delegate void QueueTask(Task task);
        public delegate void Task(QueueTask queueTask);


        public void Queue(Task task) { }
    }
}


namespace MyApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void SomeFunc()
        {
            Test.TaskPool2 taskPool = new Test.TaskPool2();


            taskPool.Queue(queue => { Console.WriteLine("A"); queue(q => Console.WriteLine("C")); });
        }
    }
}
```

Granted its somewhat convoluted!

Comment: Please post code that actually reproduces the error.

Comment: Sorry about that please see my edit!  That makes me even more curious!

Answer (score 1):

After using several ways to break\fix the code, I've found a small bit of information.

When the compiler reaches the line

```
taskPool.Queue(queue => { Console.WriteLine("A"); queue(q => Console.WriteLine("C")); });
```

it'll fall compilation if (and I think only if) it never encountered QueueTask before.
For instance, declaring the next line in the class (before or after the SomeFunc method)

```
Public Delegate Test.TaskPool2.QueueTask x;
```

would fix the compilation.
Also, adding the next line above the errornouse line will also fix it

```
Test.TaskPool2.QueueTask x; // declare x to be QueueTask
```

I've tried a few more lines using QueueTask, and they worked (fix the compilation).

I can only assume that the compiler doesn't load the definition for QueueTask, and this leads to this strangment.

Seems even like a bug.

Hope I managed to explain this well.

Answer (score 0):

(This would have been a comment, but it's not really feasible to give full code in comments.)

Your code already works as it stands:

```
delegate void Task(QueueTask queueTask);
delegate void QueueTask(Task task);

class Test
{
    void MyTask(QueueTask queueTask)
    {
        queueTask(qt => {}); // fails with queueTask doesn't take 1 parameter?
    }
}
```

Compiles with no problems.

Please create a similarly short but complete program which *doesn't* compile.

Comment: Sorry about that please see my edit.

Amazing that I got something wrong with something that does compile!